How are coefficients of a series related to its divergent behavior
This is an open problem with probably a physics background.
Suppose I have a series defined on some region $[-a, a] \subset \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} c_n x^n
$$
And I know that when $x \to a^-$, the divergent behavior of this series is
$$
f(x) \sim \frac{A}{x-a}
$$
What can we say about the coefficients $c_n$ of the series?
If this question is too general, what conditions should I impose on the series to allow me to say something about the coefficients.

what answer are you looking for? note that you can always wiggle $c_n$ a little (or add to them coefficients of holomorphic functions on a sligthly larger interval) and do not change the behaviour at $a^-$

Since your statements indicate that $f$ does not converge at $a$, but does converge for all $x < a$ in a neighborhood of $a$, we can say that the radius of convergence of the power series must be $a$. Which means $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|} = \frac 1a$$
